# Tomcat5.5 Page load time

Tags: tomcat5.5

I have multiple websites running on Tomcat:

```
<Context path="/foo"......</Context>
<Context path="/bar"......</Context>
```

When I surf to one of the applications, it takes approx. 3 minutes to load. However, if I hit the refresh button midway through the 3 minute wait/load time, the site comes up right away.
In general, is there an explanation for this behavior (having the site come up faster after the refresh button is hit)?

Comment: sounds like your browser has cached some static content, which reduced the loading time for your second visit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any reports of similar behaviour with Tomcat of any version.

It sounds like the client is waiting for more data when in fact the server has sent it all. That sort of thing can happen if there is a mis-match between the content length header and the actual content sent and the connection ends up waiting for a timeout.

In your position, I'd be considering the following:
- use thread dumps on the Tomcat side to see what Tomcat is doing in terms of request processing.
- using a browser plug-in (ieHttpHeaders, FireBug etc) that shows headers and data 
- using Wireshark to see exactly what is sent when on the network

and pay careful attention to content length headers and actual content length.